DC DC boost giving high voltage , minimum quiescent current
My dc-dc gives 25 V on load instead of 5 V, Arduino calculator shows similar values for 3 V supply.
Supply is 3 V 2 AA batteries.
Led blinking ON for 100 msec OFF 900 msec, current 150mA
The intended load is 5V, to run 5 LED in parallel at 150 mA total current.
Base resistor is 3.3 kΩ, inductor 47 µH.
Square wave oscillator uses 470 kΩ and 100 nF capacitor running on 74HC14. Also used SMD values 1 kΩ & 4.7 nF, giving 110 kHz.
How to get 5 V and 150 mA output?
Transistor should go into saturation, need minimum quiescent current required to save battery current.    Ripple can be 0.3 V.
Update: I tried 10 nF, 100 nF, the cap at HC14 osc, still voltage is above 18 V.
Update: 2 smd pcb boards were assembled. Board 1 gives 5V , board 2 gives 25 V.
Board1 has SS14 diode, base resistor 1k , 22mH inductor.
Board2 has BAT65 diode, base resistor 2k2 , 47mH inductor.
Transistor used is 2n2222.
Load and no load has little change in voltage around 3.5 V



Try to adjust the duty-cycle of the square wave.
But you will also need some feedback mechanism to keep the output stable. Or you need to attach a load that have similar characteristics as your LEDs, then adjust the duty cycle.

How to adjust on 74hc04 , used smd values 1k ohm & 4.7nF , 110khz

So how did you calculate those values of 1 k ohm, 4.7nF etc?

Put LEDs in series. Adjust the series resistor. You might not have to adjust your circuit at all.

With or without a load?

What’s your load? What’s your feedback mechanism?

This is a very rough, entirely uncontrolled boost converter. Look into proper converters like an AP3012 or LM2577.

You should use a 1N5812R for the diode and change the base resistor (300 Ohm min). Duty = ~ 55 %. You should obtain Vo=~ 5.5V with 160 mA current load (efficiency = ~78 %). NB: you should add also a "regulator", otherwise voltage output is "great").

If too "high", BJT will not be "on" completely. Note that the voltage oscillator is also "low". Ic goes from 240 mA to 480 mA. Ib is about 8 mA.

Complete and correct schematic is required to diagnose this for anyone but you. VTC.

Your requirement is clear. I will provide you with a complete circuit that modifies this to do what you want. We built thousands of them in Taiwan 20+:years ago. I will reopen your question but please add a brief diagram change showing the load although it is not necessary to understand the question.

I am a moderator. DO NOT tell people how to do things when they come to help you. eg telling someone to simulate your circuit can easily seem to be rude, even if that is not intended, and will result in people being far less helpful than they could be

@winny going thru other posts I found that you are fond of simulators . Microcap gives different current consumption for different time steps ( the settings in limits)

@Hars Indeed. Use a timestep low enough to give realistic results.

This circuit works well.
It's not pretty, but it works superbly.
You could adapt the shown regulator to suit your own system, or could create a simpler one based on the same principle.
Example only: A zener diode fronm the output to the oscillator gate input would pull up the oscillator input when Vout exceeded the zener voltage "plus a little".  This turns off the transistor.


Here is a related post from "The PICList in 2010"

I did something extremely similar* some years ago - even extending to the LDO with one Vbe drop which I used to
drive the SMPS feedback.


I guess in retrospect that I expected the drive clamp to work on whole cycles when regulation was reached BUT what actually
happened was that it adjusted the length of the drive pulses to maintain very smooth cycle by cycle regulation.
Intuitive in hindsight but a pleasant discovery at the time.


... It was used to provide a stable local supply for the logic core in the face of widely varying battery voltage** and
sudden very large and noisy electromechanical battery loads. AFAIR the CD40106 smps and 2 x LDOs quiescent
current loads and some logic idled "in regulation" at slightly under 100 microamps. (** 4 x C cells and some logic rated
at nominal 5 volts. Not a marvellous design initially).


Here we are. Seemed worth digging up.
Y' don't buy no ugly SMPS!
I hacked this out of the middle of a jpg with other irrelevant stuff
in it and cut and pasted it into left to right alignment using
Irfanview so the result is even less beautiful than the ugly original.
LH inverter is an oscillator with 2 x R + diode providing asymmetric mark/space.
RH inverter (RHI) drives transistor to provide drive to L21 which
"rings" to > Vbattery when Q21 is turned off.
When voltage on C22 at input of LDO regulator rises a Vbe drop =about
0.5 Volt above regulator output then Q22 starts to turn on.
If Q22 is turned partially on it will pull input of RHI high thereby
stopping drive to Q21.
The squeamish may wish to put a resistor betwixt Q22c and RHI pin 3.
If Q22 was turn hard on the drive would cease suddenly until C22
voltage fell far enough to turn Q22 off.
In practice Q22 turns on enough to be "modulated" by rising V_C22 to
reduce the effective length of the drive pulses to Q21. Look at it too
too hard and the logic begins to fail, but in practice this is what
happens.
The arrangement with Q22 and IC22 means that the LDO regulator is
always supplied with a voltage about 0.5 volt above its output. As
long as the LDO does not drop out with this delta-V it works well.
I show an LM2950, which is good enough for this, but the final version
used a superb and approx zero cost Taiwanese sourced LDO.
Frequency, mark space ratio and inductor values can be arranged to
suit. This would work well enough at milliWatts to Watts.
The 40106 allows very low Iq with no load.
I left R26 in, although its purpose is obscure - presumably it snubbed
a slight transient. Inductor value is high, reflecting low power level
here.
Note that the oscillator is loaded by the modulation but not stopped
and that right hand inverter only needs a sniff of signal SO this
system could 'borrow" a clock from anywhere available and us only a
single inverter. OR replace RH inverter with a MOSFET and pullup and
get a discrete parts add on smps.
1 x MOSFET, 2 x bipolar, L, C, LDO.

@Hars  AIC1722. Datasheet here  . You can get them on Ali express and maybe from "more reliable" channels.

Working off your design:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You're going to have to modify R1 and/or R2 to adjust the frequency and duty cycle. Bigger R1 will give you lower frequency and lower duty cycle which will amount to lower voltage. I don't have any useful formulas for frequency and duty cycle; the ones I know won't be very precise for this. It's best you optimize this with an equivalent load resistor, tweak R1 and R2 until you get the desired operating point, then put the LED load back in circuit. That's what I would do in real life. Also, this isn't a regulator. So the output will be affected by input voltage and output loading to some degree. Fortunately, your load is constant and tolerant to poor regulation.

So this gives 5V 150mA with 3V input ? What about minimum quiescent current for the transistor , battery drain should be minimum.

@Hars Probably not.

@Antonio51 and at user Mosfet ty.  Gives 7V when base resistor is 10k , osc cap 10nf . I will try your values

@Hars the capacitor should have little effect on the output voltage. It's the resistors that govern the voltage.

I meant base resistor for the transistor

@Hars The base resistor doesn't matter - it needs to be high enough to not overload the inverter gate, and low enough to drive the transistor into saturation. If the base resistor is influencing the voltage, then you likely need a lower value. I would go with 560 ohms without even doing the math. Maybe even 330 ohms. I don't know what your peak inductor current is.

issue here is I get very high voltage of 21 V ( on load,  4 led parallel 5mm ).  I need 5V . 1st pcb gives correct voltage , 2nd pcb gives 21V  . See the variations in 1st and 2nd pcb in main question.

@Hars Not clear what you are trying to say: "I get very high voltage of 21 V ( on load, 4 led parallel 5mm )" I told you how to address that - Make R1 bigger. Then, you say "1st pcb gives correct voltage" So what's the problem? That's what you want. Just use PCB 1.


How to get 5 V and 150 mA?

Some modifications could be made, adding an equal "load" (5 / 0.15 = ~ 35 Ohm).
Changing also resistor base.
Simulated with microcap v12.


Note that without the "load", voltage output may be much "higher".

300 R at base draws around 0.05 mA (avg) into the ground ?  Can we reduce it to 150uA

No. I don't think. I simulated ~ 5-8 mA current base as just the "minimum" for the 2N2222 (Beta =200).

I will use mosfet si2303 , bss138 , what will be the gate resistor

microcap step value (in limit menu) when changed gives different current consumption for different time steps .

Are you "waiting" for the "steady state" values?

I high lighted current icon and ran transient response . Gives 300mA in step setting , and 30mA in another step setting , current at battery side
